# Google Analytics conflict with video embed code

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-analytics, youtube

All of a sudden, our Youtube and Facebook embedded videos are not rendering. If I comment out the basic GA code snippet, it works fine. Google analytics is still tracking.

Is there some sort of conflict between these two?

GA:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o [0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Video embed:

```
     (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


          var tag = document.createElement('script');
          tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
          var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
          firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);



          var player;
          function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
              playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 1,'autohide':1,'wmode':'opaque' },
              videoId: 'xxxxxxxxx',
              events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady}
            });
          }


          function onPlayerReady(event) {
            event.target.mute();
          }
```

Update: 
After not making any material changes, it seemed to be fixed, but now the problem has returned. Also, I am using Facebook comments, which are also not rendering. If anyone has any ideas what might be causing this conflict between the GA snippet and the FB and YT APIs, that's would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Really stange behavior: usually GA does not conflicting with YouTube or Facevook videos.
I think make sense to identify type of conflict - for this may be helpful to check browser JS console(for warnings/errors in ../analytics.js or conflicting variable names).
Also for troubleshooting may be helpful plugin [Chome Analytics Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en).

Comment: This is the error in the console: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.facebook.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://www.example.com"  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match. Any ideas?

Comment: The only idea is to remove protocol(http:) from the youtube video src and change "http://www.youtube.com/player_api"  to "//www.youtube.com/player_api": as in GA and FB scripts this was already done